# ReportViewer in VS 2013 not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

Using Web Forms Applications, I added a new web form, added a Script Manager then under it the Report Viewer. At this point if I view it in browser shouldn't at least the Report Viewer's toolbar be visible? Under properties all are True for visibility. I am new to this and I'm completely stuck.. please help!

Comment: Figured it out with the help of a friend.
Right-click ReportViewer, select view code, added the following: 
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList2.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath =
                "/" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "/" + DropDownList2.Text;
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportViewer1.Visible = false;
    }
}

Comment: Then in the DropDownList2 properties, Events, Actions, SelectedIndexChanged, DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged.